# Check uploading file is password protected or not in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, file-upload, password-protection

Please help me on this.

I have some file upload functionality in my application which is implemented using Javascript/jQuery on the front-end and an AJAX call to send the file object to the back-end written in Java.

I need to detect if the file uploaded is password protected. If it is then I want to throw an error to the user.

Is there an option to check this on the front-end using Javascript/jQuery or should I do it in the back end?

In my Java middle-ware I am using the SmartUpload class to fetch the file object and insert it into a DB (blob format).

Please suggest which is better and why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the file type?

Comment: Files can be either PDF or image(JPEG/JPG/PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is how you can check if a pdf file is encrypted or not in java.

See the sample below

```
try
{
    document = PDDocument.load( "C:\\abc.pdf");

    if(document.isEncrypted())
    {
      //Then the pdf file is encrypeted.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. I found this solution too.. Problem is in my case, am able to get only the file name when i try to get the actual file path, which when provided in the load method of PDDocument throws file not found:( Correct me if am doing something wrong.

Comment: It worked Manish. Thanks. I had made a minor mistake handling the variable with the file path. It works now.:) I just want to know, if there could be any solution to check in the front end to avoid back end request.  If any, please post here.